# Populating dataframe with dict that has diffrent length values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I Am doing some web scraping and making a csv with the scraped data.

I created a dataframe with columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'type', 'regular_price', 'Image src', 'Attribute 1 name', 'Attribute 1 value(s)', 'Attribute 2 name', 'Attribute 2 value(s)', 'Attribute 1 visible', 'Attribute 1 global', 'Attribute 2 visible', 'Attribute 2 global'])
```

I am looping over all my links and pulling data page by page and appending it to the dataframe with this:

```
df = df.append({'name':names,'type':'variable', 'regular_price':combprice, 'Image src':'1', 'Attribute 1 name':'Color' ,'Attribute 1 value(s)':'2' ,'Attribute 2 name':'Size' ,'Attribute 2 value(s)':sizes ,'Attribute 1 visible':'1' ,'Attribute 1 global':'1' ,'Attribute 2 visible':'1' ,'Attribute 2 global':'1'}, ignore_index=True)
```

I had all columns working except 'regular_price' and 'Image src', I did have 'Attribute 1 value(s)' Working. Although now it is not.

After each loop I am doing:

```
df.at[count, 'Image src'] = images
df.at[count, 'Attribute 1 value(s)'] = colors
```

Also the fact that 'regular_price' isn't being populated is weird because I can print the values with no issues, same with the 'images' list

I Changed the lists to a dict and tried with that but I still get array lengths must be of all equal value.

Am I wrong appending to the dataframe with df.at after inserting equal values into the row?

I can't seem to get anywhere with this any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's the error you get, can you show the traceback please

Comment: I'm not infront if a computer but its dataframe arrays must be all if equal length.

Comment: Seems dataframes don't want to add a list of key values